# Do/Should Shared Libraries (libNNN.so) Share Const Data?

Tags: c++, linux

There was a question similar to this one, but w/o the answer targeted at static, *const* data (read only data) an a linux system. 
This is the situation:
A shared library is being used by many programs on the system. That shared library has a large amount of const data. Will that const data be replicated in system memory for each process that links to (and uses) the shared library?
I understand (or think I do) that the size of the shared library is counted against it at a "high" level, but that *under the covers* Linux will not swap out duplicate copies of the executable section. Is this also true for the static (namespace level) const data?

Comment: +1, important question for me also. You can add a question B for non constant, read+write data.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If the shared object `libNNN.so` has data in a read only segment (e.g. from a `.rodata` or `.text` section), then that segment is [mmap](http://linux.die.net/man/2/mmap)-ed with `MAP_SHARED` by `dlopen` or `ld.so` so different processes (loading that `libNNN.so`) using that read-only data are indeed sharing the physical RAM containing it.

The static or global read-write data is going into a `MAP_PRIVATE` read-write `mmap`-ed segment (from `.bss` or `.data` sections) so each process has its own (still copied-on-write).

Use `objdump` to find out what segments are inside a `libNNN.so`

Use `pmap`  or `/proc/1234/maps` to learn about the memory mapping of process of pid 1234. (From inside the application, read sequentially `/proc/self/maps` if needed, or `/proc/self/statm` if you want to measure).

<sup>notice that `const` things in C often go into `.rodata`, but with C++ constructed data this is no more the case</sup>

Comment: the DSO-howto has a thorough treatment of how to `const`-ify data and avoid relocations.